# Привязка свойства Visibility к свойству EF-объекта

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

Имеется небольшой проект, в котором для генерации базы данных используется EF CodeFirst. Все классы сущностей наследуются от базового абстрактного класса:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
     [Key]
     public int ID {get;set;};
     public bool Invisible { get; set; }
}
```

В клиентском приложении, которое я пишу на WPF, используется паттерн MVVM. Так вот, в одной из вьюшек декларирован DataGrid, в качестве ItemsSource для которого указана коллекция объектов сущности, которая наследуется от вышеупомянутого базового абстрактного класса.

*Вопрос: Куда забиндить свойство Invisible, чтобы в DataGrid отображались, соответственно, только те объекты коллекции, у которых это значение равно false?*

Comment: _"чтобы в DataGrid отображались, соответственно, только те объекты коллекции, у которых это значение равно false"_ -- для фильтрации надо использовать CollectionView. и в свойстве Filter делаете фильтрацию элементов.

Comment: Т.е. предварительно в бизнес-слое привести результат запрос к CollectionView, отфильтровать, а потом передать её в UI и завернуть в ObservableCollection? Или как?

Comment: _"в бизнес-слое привести запрос к CollectionView, отфильтровать, а потом передать её в UI и завернуть в ObservableCollection?"_ -- нет. в xaml определить `<CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding}" x:Key="cv">...`, а DataGrid привязывается к `{StaticResource cv}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам не нужно связывать свойство элемента коллекции чтобы его скрывать. Отфильтруйте коллекцию в модели при инициализации через `.Where(t => !t.Invisible)`.

(кстати, `IsInvisible` смотрится лучше).

Если критично не фильтровать в модели, можно написать конвертер для коллекции.

```
public class InvisibleRemoverConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var collection = (ObservableCollection<BaseEntity>)value;

        return collection.Where(t => !t.Invisible);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

В разметке соответственно

```
<GridView>
     <GridView.ItemsSource>
         <Binding Path="MyCollection">
             <Binding.Converter>
                 <myNameSpace:InvisibleRemoverConverter />
             </Binding.Converter>
         </Binding>
     </GridView.ItemsSource>
</GridView>
```

Answer (score 4):

Вы не должны использовать EF-объекты в качестве DataContext'а. Никогда.

Объекты, используемые в качестве DataContext'а, должны быть VM-объектами: имплементировать `INotifyPropertyChanged` или что-то равносильное, и жить в UI-потоке. Entity базы данных представляют собой чисто модельные объекты.

Код, устанавливающий `ItemsSource` равным коллекции EF-объектов (ещё небось `IQueryable`, так что небольшое изменение UI будет вызывать перечитывание базы) — ошибка.

---

Вы должны создать VM-объекты, соответствующие вашим EF-сущностям, положить в них нужные свойства, и реализовать INPC. Теперь вы можете отфильтровать вашу коллекцию, и передать в `ItemsSource` только нужные элементы. Или использовать фильтр (создать `ICollectionView` и отфильтровать нужное в нём).

---

Обновление: если вы пользуетесь паттерном MVVM, у вас должно быть чёткое разделение между классами модели и VM. Классы EF принадлежат уровню модели, на них свои требования по имплементации и времени жизни. Они никогда не должны быть видны в UI.

Если вы хотите реально показывать объекты базы данных в вашем UI, вам придётся создать VM-аналоги этих объектов. Но обычно вам хочется показать объект не так, как он лежит в базе, а в другом виде. Например, многие поля вам просто не нужны, другие имеет смысл превратить, например, из числа в Enum, а третьи объединить в общий подобъект. Вы проектируете ваш VM-объект так, как *вам* нужно, а не так, как нужно *базе данных*.

При этом я бы советовал избегать кода наподобие вот такого:

```
// не делайте так!
class UserVM : VM
{
    Entities.User user;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return user.Name; }
        set { user.Name = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }
    // и т. д.
}
```

Потому что вы таким образом всё равно неявно протягиваете модельный объект в UI, а значит, чтение свойства UI-фреймворком потенциально может уйти вниз, до уровня базы! (Представьте, как будет тормозить ваш интерфейс.)

Вы, конечно, как архитектор собственного проекта *можете* выставить entity в UI и пинками заставить этот код работать, игнорируя правила MVVM. Но тогда вы отходите от паттерна MVVM, и остаётесь один на один с вашими проблемами.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34819/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd---visibility---ef-).